# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to launch activity from presenter using view interface

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change from one screen to another after a user has signed up. The user is created but I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when I call the view interface from the presenter.
Here is the part in the presenter that creates the user and prompts the change to a login screen.

```
public void signUp() {
        postUserUseCase.setWyat_user(user);

    subscription = postUserUseCase
            .execute()
            .subscribeOn(rx.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("complete","complete");
                    signUpView.showLoginScreen();


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(User user) {
                    Log.d("next",user.getEmail());

                }
            });
}
```

SignupActivity implements the view interface's showLoginScreen method.

```
  public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignUpView {

  @Override
    public void showLoginScreen() {
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);

}
```

}

The user is created but I get a null pointer onCompleted.

EDIT:
This is different from [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) because if I did the initializing of an interface I get a whole class with the methods that my activity will override. This is a view interface not a variable or a class.I just want to call on method.

EDIT 2: Logcat for the error.

> 01-14 14:41:49.359 28309-28309/com.wyat.wyat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on
>   Scheduler.Worker thread.
>                                                                      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                   Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnCompletedFailedException
>                                                                      at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onCompleted(SafeSubscriber.java:90)
>                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:272)
>                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:207)
>                                                                      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
>                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                      at com.wyat.wyat.accounts.presenters.SignUpPresenter$1.onCompleted(SignUpPresenter.java:92)
>                                                                      at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onCompleted(SafeSubscriber.java:84)
>                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:272) 
>                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:207) 
>                                                                      at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ read my edit. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: can u post the logcat error trace?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I have added the logcat.

Comment: have you initialized `signupView`?

Comment: @akash93 How would I initialize an interface?

Comment: you initialize it to the activity so that the activity's implementation is called

Comment: Yes I have done that. SignUpActivity implements SignUpView.

Comment: @akash93 I have created a method in SignUpView to attach it to the activity and I can initialize it from there. Thanks for the help.